# When we should create separated Directory for Views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have recently started learning ASP.Net Core technology and came across one thing that I can't understand. In project i have mainly HTML file **_Layout** where i have style declaration, head, footer and etc.

My directory tree looks like this

[image]
,

**About.cshtml**, **Contact.cshtml**, **Index.cshtml** and **Privacy.cshtml** are separate pages selected from the menu. In addition, the files are located in a directory called **Home**

In other project I saw this structure of the project

[image]

In this case, we divide all pages into several different directories. I can't understand when to create subsequent pages / views in one directory, and when to create separate directories for views.

Comment: It is always optional and what you prefer, but typically think about creating different 'directories' when you create a new controller or model. So say there is a book model, you would create a book controller, and then create a book view. In the book view, create all of the necessary pages for the book, like Create, Index, Edit,Delete, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to think of it as a 'directory' or folder for every model. Im sure there are other opinions, but if I create a new model, I typically will add a new controller, and most actions in the controller, will come with its own page. If I create a `books` model

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Author {get;set;}
    public DateTime PublishDate {get;set;}
}
```

Then I create a `Books` controller, and say in the controller I have the typical `Index`, `Create`, `Edit` actions. Then I will create a new folder in `Views` named `Books`, and in that folder I will create the `Index.cshtml`, `Edit.cshtml`, `Create.cshtml` views, and whatever action I create in the controller for `Books`, if it returns a view, then I will create that `.cshtml` file in the `Books` folder.